# Why copy an event handler into another variable

Tags: c#

In an example, I find this code:

```
public event EventHandler ThresholdReached;

protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
{
  EventHandler handler = ThresholdReached;
  if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
}
```

I would like to understand the reason for the line:

```
EventHandler handler = ThresholdReached;
```

Can we not just do it this way:

```
public event EventHandler ThresholdReached;

protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(EventArgs e)
{
  if (ThresholdReached != null)
            ThresholdReached(this, e);
}
```

Are there some advantages/disadvantages to either way of doing it?

Comment: [Clean event handler invocation with C# 6](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/)

Comment: It is boilerplate, avoids a threading race bug that can occur when another thread unsubscribes the event.  Nothing pretty about calling an event handler after it was unsubscribed either.  It is the kind of code that Microsoft needs to write to avoid their customers calling them, you'll be far happier with the NullReferenceException in your own code.  You'll need that help that diagnose such bugs.

Comment: The reason is **thread safety**: we copy `ThresholdReached` content into *local variable* and only then execute. If some other thread change `ThresholdReached`, `handler` will not be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that between this line

```
if (ThresholdReached != null)
```

and this line

```
ThresholdReached(this, e);
```

a different thread could have removed the handlers from the `ThresholdReached` event. So it would be `null` and an exception would be thrown.

By storing the value in a local variable, you make the call thread-safe.

Since C# 6 you can shorten the code to this

```
ThresholdReached?.Invoke(this, e);
```

Now the compiler takes care of storing the value in a temporary variable.

Answer (score 4):

There's a theoretical risk of a thread race in the second version where someone unsubscribes the event between the check and the invoke, causing a `NullReferenceException` in the invoke step. Capturing the value into a local and testing/invoking *that* prevents this. However, perhaps use the third version, possible with C# 6 or above (thanks @Cid):

```cs
ThresholdReached?.Invoke(this, e);
```

This is *basically* a short-hand version of the first version - all the safety, but now with terseness.